# Who killed more people, Luke or Vader?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, luke-skywalker, death-star, kill-count

We know from the Death Star Technical Companion that the number of people aboard the first Death Star (including troopers, gunners, crew, pilots, staff, etc.) was 1,179,293. That's how many people Luke killed in a single Force-inspired instant. Then you add all the other people he's killed in his adventures (though as a friend of mine has said, that's essentially a rounding error in the death toll).

How does that compare to the number of people directly killed by Darth Vader (including the sand people, even if he was technically still Anakin then) over his lifespan, off-screen or on?

Comment: Does this include the people of Alderaan? If so, definitely Vader.

Comment: I wouldn't include Alderaan. That was Tarkin's move, not Vader's.

Comment: Unless Vader _Forced_ that on Tarkin.

Comment: I feel like you've answered your own question. Vader might be the Emperor's bagman but I don't think he's gone around killing people by their millions.

Comment: The question itself is a trap though. To really express the impact of Vader's choices, you have to account somehow for all the people who died because Vader chose to help Palpatine. Every death after that is some amount of blood on his hands, whether he personally killed them or not.

Comment: Vader could have intervened to stop Tarkin...

Comment: Vader also failed to stop Luke racking up his megadeath...

Comment: In ESB, Vader orders several Star Destroyers, each containing THOUSANDS of people, into an asteroid field. At least one of the Destroyers is... destroyed, and all of them took significant damage and probably sustained casualties.   Does that count?

Comment: And what about scenes where we see Vader prepare to kill people, the camera cuts away, and then we see him afterwards and he basically says "I totally killed all those people"?  Like the Younglings at the temple?

Comment: Are non-human aliens and animals people?  Do Wampas and Rancors count?  What about droids?

Comment: Please [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/116010/edit) your question to clarify what your criteria for killing is,  and address the comments asking for more detail.

Comment: @ancientswordrage - A canonical answer exists for this question.

Comment: @Valorum several answers exist. Until the question is clarified, I don't see the benefits of reopening. I'll stands by any community consensus though.  Feel free to post on meta.

Answer (score 0):

### Luke killed way more (at least in the movies)

Mr. Sunday Movies has put together some excellent compilations of their kills.

The results are:

### [Luke](https://youtu.be/q_IGDcPprjg): 369,470

### [Vader](https://youtu.be/JZtqh5FK1yc): 60

Comment: Vader orders several Star Destroyers, each containing THOUSANDS of people, into an asteroid field.  At least one of the Destroyers is...  destroyed, and all of them took significant damage and probably sustained casualties.

Comment: @WadCheber I would assume that the video is not counting that because Vader wasn't the one who actually destroyed the Destroyer.

Comment: I'd have to argue that the video is wrong, then.

Comment: @WadCheber Leave a YouTube comment :)

Comment: It also counts the Rancor as a "person"...  Even if it was, he didn't kill it.  He closed a door, and the door *happened* to crush its skull.  :)

Comment: Wampas ain't people either.

Comment: @WadCheber:   Oh, come now.   [I'm just going to swing my arms like this, and if you get hit, it's you fault](http://i.imgur.com/FMeTXdm.gifv).