# What was Deadpool's line about the two Professor X's?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

At some point in the Deadpool movie, Deadpool makes a joke about the two different actors who played Professor X.

Does anyone know the exact wording of his line?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In response to Colossus's line:

> Let's go see the professor.

Deadpool replies:

> McAvoy or Stewart? These timelines are confusing!

Sources:

[looper.com](http://www.looper.com/9890/deadpools-biggest-easter-eggs/)

[cinemablend.com](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/30-Funniest-Deadpool-Quotes-112257-p3.html)

[mashable.com](http://mashable.com/2016/02/16/deadpool-4th-wall-breaks/)

[imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/quotes?item=qt2791653)

Comment: @apollo The quote on imdb differs in wording: ***Colossus:** You will gonna talk with professor Xavier.
**Deadpool:** McAvoy or Stewart? These timelines can get so confusing.*. Is imdb less unreliable than mashable?

Comment: This is all presumably done by ear; Colossus's line was less memorable and spoken in a heavy accent. Can anyone who has seen the movie repeatedly weigh in? In any case, the preceding line was not the question.

Comment: @ibid IMDb quotes are inputs from users. Mashable is probably the same.  The movie script is not around yet and this convo was not in the leaked version. I only remember what Wade said to Colossus. Since Colossus uses an accent, users might have distorted his line in order to make it more reliable (I know). And you asked Wade's line, not Colossus'.

Comment: @apollo Yeah, it was a poor choice of words on my part, but I really wanted the whole joke.

Comment: @ibid You have to go see the movie or wait for the new script to leak online. I remember what Colossus said partially because there were so many great jokes and references in the movie, I could hardly catch my breath at some points. There are easter eggs videos on youtube about this. Here is one of them: (https://youtu.be/dBdiEaTs1ko?t=130)

Comment: @apollo - Last time that I [posted an answer from Mr. Sunday Movies](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116032/55866), it didn't get any upvotes.

Comment: Now that dvd/bluray is out, care to update with a definitive source?