# How many people has Luke Skywalker killed?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, kill-count

Is there an estimate for the number of individuals killed by Luke Skywalker?

There must have been thousands of beings on the first Death Star, but the movies don't give a specific kill count. So how many people including but not limited to Death Star casualties?

Comment: Millions. But they were all baddies, so that's ok.

Comment: Although the dupe doesn't take into account *individuals* killed by Luke, the reality is that the number pales into insignificance compared to the number that he killed when he singlehandedly blew up the Death Star 1.

Comment: The Death Star + a few dozen more.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. The answers to the "duplicate" question don't cover this because they only take into account the Death Star, not people Luke might have killed through other mechanisms. The Death Stars probably had the largest contribution, but that doesn't make this a dupe.

Comment: I'm with @Jonah here. He may have only killed very few others, but those may have been meaningful or higher impact kills.

Comment: Who cares about that, I want to know how many womp rats he killed.

Comment: This question is nearly impossible to answer fully since there is no way of knowing the exact number of people on the Death Star and there is no way to account for any kills he got in battles that happen in between the movies nor can we account for all of his kills in any battle due to any accidental kills or kills due to any explosions that he may have caused and any collateral damage that he could be responsible for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Movies: 369,466

369,466 people, from [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_IGDcPprjg) referenced in Rogue Jedi's answer.

But movies aren't the only high-level canon anymore!

### Star Wars: Shattered Empire, Part IV : At least 5

- Luke blows up an Imperial Commandant and at least three stormtroopers.
  [image]

He also appears to kill at least one more stormtrooper in the preceding battle.

### Heir to the Jedi: At least 8

One Imperial agent:

> They recovered quickly after the first one cried out with a charred
> hole in his chest; whatever armor he was wearing wasn’t up to
> deflecting the heat from my blaster turned up to maximum.

Some TIE fighters, one person per fighter:

> I squeezed the blaster trigger and held it down as we approached the
> edge; two TIE fighters emerged from beneath the ship—the vanguard of
> the second squadron—caught bolts in their cockpits, and exploded. Four
> down, twenty to go—though the second squadron was still in the process
> of scrambling into action.
>
> ...
>
> But the shock wave continued in our direction, too, plowing through
> the trailing TIE fighters behind us and shuddering them apart. We
> watched on the scanner as the red triangles representing the enemy
> disappeared one by one. They kept firing green bolts, as if they were
> determined to see us dead before they died themselves. Almost all of
> it sailed past our cockpit into the void, but the concentrated fire
> was too much to dodge forever and another bolt clipped us, essentially
> wiping out our shields except for a courtesy veil of energy as sheer
> as a negligee. The fire eased up as the TIEs were destroyed, but the
> closest one with the best angle landed one on the rear starboard and,
> a fraction of a second before it was obliterated, took out the
> sublight engine there, which spelled the end for us.

Four shot initially + one agent + a "string" of fighters (at least 3) is at least 8.

Comment: So really, he's killed more than Anakin ever did.

Comment: Very unlikely. This counts only onscreen deaths. For twenty years, Anakin was the violent enforcer for an evil Empire that routinely wiped out whole populations.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_IGDcPprjg) video states that he killed 369,466<sup>1</sup> people. Given the number of people in [the first Death Star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36239/51226), [an average AT-AT](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport) and [Jabba's sail-barge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Khetanna), the numbers check out.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, technically, it states he killed 369,469 beings, but that includes three animals, which I assume you don't count.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116032/55866

Comment: In The Mandalorian someone who was on the Death Star shortly before it blew up stated that millions died.